# portable PS-viewer with forward and inverse-search

Tags: texniccenter, forward-inverse-search, postscript, portability, evince

I am using a portable Latex (Miktex, Texniccenter & Sumatrapdf) from my flashdrive and all works good. But I found no possibility to search in *.ps files through forward or inverse-search. I use Evince (also as a portable edition) for viewing *.ps files but I found no options to enable forward or inverse-search.

Is there a portable PS-viewer which understands forward and inverse-search?

Is it possible to set up forward and inverse-search with Evince? If yes, how?

If ther is no portable viewer, which other PS-viewers can use forward and inverse-search? Maybe it is possible to make it portable.

With portable I mean for different versions of the same operatingsystem. In my case windows-pcs. I am using my flashdrive at university-windows-pcs wheres no latex and so on is installed at all. So I have to bring it with me. And because there are no adminrights (for me) i cant install anything.

Comment: Do you mean simple searching or something like SyncTeX (which, afaik, is PDF-only)?

Comment: You should define what you mean by portable. Portable across different versions of the same operating system, portable across different operating systems, portable across different CPU architectures, etc. Are you willing to re-compile for the target platform or should it directly be executable or interpreted on the target platform?

Comment: @SeanAllred I mean something like SyncTex. If it is PDF-only, is there an other option to do forward and inverse-search? In YAP it is possible to do forward and inverse-search and thats DVI not PDF.

Comment: @Marco I dont know there are so much definitions of portable. I mean different versions of the same operating system. So I connect my flashdrive on a windows-pc and can execute the programms without installing something (in the best case without left something on the pc).

Comment: @Marco I believe he means portable in the sense of [portable apps](http://portableapps.com).  Now that I'm on a computer, I've done a little research and it *seems* to be possible, even though I've never used it.  (I generally don't view output until late in the process…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synctex enables forward/reverse sync with either DVI or PDF. My understanding is that in principle it is output-format-agnostic: it relies on an additional file, .synctex.gz, to collect sync information. So, in principle, one could write a PS viewer that supports it. However, as far as I know, none are currently available. See here:

http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-3/tb93laurens.pdf

Comment: The link is very usefull. After reading I understand that SyncTeX was designed for DVI and then modified to be used for PDF. Nothing to do with PS. But PS is created through command Latex (like DVI output) and DviPs (postprocessing), so eventually its possible to code something with the SyncTeX commandline tool.