# Portable Version of TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter

I have been using TeXnicCenter for a while now, and think it is a great interface.  I want to use TeXnicCenter on the computers in the Library, as they have larger monitors, better computers, and faster internet connections.  I have my USB 3.0 drive loaded with Miktex Portable, and it works fine.  Really, though, I prefer to use TeXnicCenter.

When I read through other posts [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135012/portable-ps-viewer-with-forward-and-inverse-search) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176227/is-there-a-placeholder-for-the-drive-letter-of-the-texniccenter-installation) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/latex-portable-editing-environment) they mention that it is possible to install portable TexnicCenter, but I can't find installation instructions. This [post](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latex-editors/76-latex-editors-texniccenter/354-how-to-make-texniccenter-portable) gives some ideas how to do it, but I am concerned it may be outdated.

Has anyone installed TeXnicCenter on a USB drive? Does it work well? How did you do it?

If it isn't possible, what portable platform should I use? Should I stick with MiKtex as my back end? What front end should I use?

For now I'm using TexWorks editor, which is ok, but I'd prefer something with more snazz.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is the registry.  I was going to try it, but am afraid I might undermine my current installation on the hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many many students use Texmaker Portable. All is into a single folder, with even bibtex for references. it has naturally pdflatex.

A cool advice from my side

Ask me for the zip file.

> Texmaker 4.3 (compiled with Qt 5.2.1 and Poppler 0.22.5) Copyright (c)
>   2003-2014 by Pascal Brachet Project home site :
>   http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/

Comment: Seems better then texnic center

Answer (score 1):

It's not TeXnicCenter, but it is a bit more whizz-bang than TeXWorks:

http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/

Give it a whirl.

Ttrailbarge